# Negative match regex for positive and negative numbers with decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have regex expression which ensures that any characters which do not match the following criteria are replaced by an empty string:

- Must be a number.
- Optionally can be positive or negative.
- Optionally can have decimal values, but not a trailing decimal point.

**My problem**: I am unable to figure out how to preserve the *negative sign* if it is found in front of the number. My regex currently replaces all instances of the '-' by an empty string. *I am missing something here to ensure this issue does not occur*.

```js
var testId = document.getElementById('test');

var validate = value => {
  let regex = /([^\d.-]+)|([^\.?\d]+)/g;

  return value.toString().trim().replace(regex, '');
};

// Note: in comments, the expected output
var values = [
  '12345', // 12345
  '-12345', // -12345
  '12345.6789', // 12345.6789
  '-12345.6789', // -12345.6789
  '-123-45.-6789', // -12345.6789
  '$12345a6', // 123456
  '-1abcde+^~2345.6*#zZ789', // -12345.6789
  '50-00', // 5000
  '$12345' // 12345
];

values.forEach(value => {
  testId.innerHTML += `<p>${value} ==> ${validate(value)}</p>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @anubhava will add now to the above

Comment: Try `return value.toString().trim().replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '').replace(/^([^-]*)(-)|-/g, '$2$1');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the test value 50-00 ==> -5000 which I think should instead be 5000, neat idea though

Comment: So, `return value.toString().trim().replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '').replace(/^(-)|-/g, '$1');`

Comment: Excellent, feel free to add this as an answer, I do not exactly understand how the second regex expression works if you do not mind explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
return value.toString().trim().replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '').replace(/^(-)|-/g, '$1');
```

Here,

- `.replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '')` - removes all chars other than digits, dots and hyphens
- `.replace(/^(-)|-/g, '$1')` - only keeps the first hyphen in the string and removes all other hyphens. The point is that `(-)` captures the hyphen at the start (`^` means the start of the string) into Group 1 that you can access with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern, and `|-` means "OR a hyphen that will be only matched in a non-initial position.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var testId = document.getElementById('test');

var validate = value => {
  return value.toString().trim().replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '').replace(/^(-)|-/g, '$1');
};

// Note: in comments, the expected output
var values = [
  '12345', // 12345
  '-12345', // -12345
  '12345.6789', // 12345.6789
  '-12345.6789', // -12345.6789
  '-123-45.-6789', // -12345.6789
  '$12345a6', // 123456
  '-1abcde+^~2345.6*#zZ789', // -12345.6789
  '50-00', // 5000
  '$12345' // 12345
];

values.forEach(value => {
  testId.innerHTML += `<p>${value} ==> ${validate(value)}</p>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```